# JavsScript keeps subtracting PHP/MySQL date format

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to pass a date from MySQL via PHP into JavaScript and instead of displaying the date correctly, it subtracts the date. How can I stop JavaScript from doing basic math?

from html doc #1

```
<button type="submit" onclick="getbookingpricingtable(2019-08-20,2019-08-25);" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Select</button>
```

to doc #2:

```
  function getbookingpricingtable(str1, str2) {
    var startdate = str1;
    var enddate = str2;
}
```

Gives me 1991 and 1986

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the provided snippet both arguments of the `getbookingpricingtable` are provided as numbers and thus evaluated. To pass the entire date the values can be passed as string. Check out the following example(Notice the `'` around the dates):

```
<button type="submit" onclick="getbookingpricingtable('2019-08-20','2019-08-25');" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Select</button>
```